# Malware links in Chrome and SafeZone

Tags: google-chrome

When I go to http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h using Chrome, in bottom panel, instead of code result, I see some images, i.e. links to `www.adskeeper.co.uk...`.

The same images appear using Avast SafeZone browser.

Using Opera - the images don't appear.

I tried:
- Remove all extensions from Chrome
- Reinstall Chrome
- Scan and reboot system using Malwarebytes, Adwcleaner, Avast... without success.

Any help?